# Adding hover pop-up notes to map Arcmap desktop 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, point

I have a layer of points defining a variety of geologic features overlying a global map.  I would like the user to be able to hover over a point and see a description of that feature.  Hyperlinks would be too complicated for this purpose.  Are hover-able map notes possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to [turn on map tips](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Displaying_MapTips).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to enable map tips when we export the map to pdf? shame there isn't an option to make the pdf interactive using Arcmap (other than turning layers on and off).

Comment: I don't think so from an ArcMap perspective, though I think there are ways to show tips on PDF's.  I am not sure how that works though.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Is a way to wrap the text in maptips? Python or VBScript?

Comment: Yes, you can hit the "Expression" button to build your own expression there.  You can add line breaks wherever you want.